# Javascript: Find and delete *all* repeated items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with the following elements:

```
A
B
B
C
B
```

If an item appears more than once, I have to delete all its occurrences. Therefore, it would be like this:

```
A
C
```

I have found lots of examples on how to remove the other repeated elements but still leave the "original" one, out of that I couldn't find anything closer to it and I am really lost.

I have thought about saving in a object the following:
1. The item's value;
2. How many times it appears;
3. The position of all the appearances.

If the times appeared was more than 1, I would remove all of the following positions in the array. Is it a good idea? What would be the best way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: To clarify, you only want to modify the original array, not create a new one with the elements from the original array removed?

Comment: One way could be to create a new array and only push original values by check if value already exists in the new array. Maybe not the best solution, but is one way :P

Comment: @Daryl It would be better if it was in a new array :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using `filter()` and return only unique elements by checking if `indexOf` is equal to `lastIndexOf`

```js
var ar = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B'];
var result = ar.filter(function(e) {
  return ar.indexOf(e) == ar.lastIndexOf(e);
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Nenad, Nice!  And instead of `ar.indexOf(e)` you could use the current index that `filter` already give us, on its second parameter, to compare against `ar.lastIndexOf(e)`. The signature is `filter(element, index, array)`

Comment: the callback is not reusable.

Comment: @PossessWithin You're welcome.

Comment: Even though this answer looks cool it does tons of `lastIndexOf()` operation. Best would be to use a hash and filter for value 1.